# Get custom object Id in standalone Aura Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura, visualforce-component, salesforce-id

I have an aura component that is launched from a custom hyperlink made with form assembly and is not on the detail page of any records.  From what I understand, this means the "force:hasRecordId" will not work, and it is null when I try to reference it this way.  I have everything working in my apex class when I pass a hard-coded Id to the "enrollmentId" parameter in my "getOOSPOptions" method, but no matter what I try I can't seem to grab the enrollment Id (v.oospid) value properly.  The enrollment Id is the Id of the custom "enrollment" record which contains the link to the app.  The app URL references the related "institution" Id which I don't want.  The strange thing is that the enrollment Id (v.oospid) seems to be referenced fine later down in the existing code, so I know it is possible.  Any help would be appreciated.  I am still a bit confused on how the data is passed around and I feel like I have tried everything.

**OOSPController**

```
}).then(() => {
            helper.getOOSPOptions(component, event, helper).then(options => {
                component.set("v.cipOptions", options.cipOptions);
                component.set("v.stateOptions", options.stateOptions);
            }).catch(error => {
                helper.toast(
                    "There was an error",
                    error.message,
                    "error",
                    "sticky",
                    5000
                );
            });
```

**Section of controller where oospid works**

```
}).then(() => {
            helper.getOOSPEnrollment(component, event, helper).then(enrollment => {
                component.set("v.oospId", enrollment.Id);
                component.set("v.oospDetailRecords", enrollment.Experiential_Enrollment_Details__r);
                component.set("v.hasNoDetails", enrollment.Has_No_OOSP_To_Report__c);
                component.set("v.oospRecord", enrollment);
                component.find("branchActivity").set("v.value", enrollment.Out_Of_State_Branch_Activity__c);
                helper.calcDetailCounts(component, enrollment.Experiential_Enrollment_Details__r);
                helper.showHideDetails(component, helper);
                helper.showHide(component, "spinner", false);
```

**OOSPHelper**

```
getOOSPOptions : function(component, event, helper) {
        return new Promise($A.getCallback((resolve, reject) => {
            var action = component.get("c.getOOSPOptions");
            //var enrollmentId = component.get("v.oospid");
            var enrollmentId = 'a0r1R00000qp9FBQAY';
            console.log(enrollmentId);
            action.setParams({
                "enrollmentId" : enrollmentId
            });
            
            action.setCallback(this, function(response){
                var state = response.getState();

                if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                    // console.log(JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
                    resolve(response.getReturnValue());
                } else if(state === "ERROR"){
                    var errors = response.getError();
                    console.log(errors[0].message);
                    reject(errors);
                }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }));
```

**OOSP Apex Controller**

```
 @AuraEnabled
    public static OOSPOptions getOOSPOptions(String enrollmentId) {
        Id enrollmentIdVal;
        if(!String.isBlank(enrollmentId)) {
            enrollmentIdVal = Id.valueOf(enrollmentId);
        }
        else{
            System.debug('Invalid OOSPEnrollmentId: ' + enrollmentId);
            Throw new AuraHandledException('The Out of State Placement for this reporting period is invalid. Please contact NC-SARA.');
        }
        List<PicklistOption> cipOptions = new List<PicklistOption>();
        List<PicklistOption> stateOptions = new List<PicklistOption>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult cipFieldResult = Experiential_Enrollment_Detail__c.CIP_Type__c.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> cipPLE = cipFieldResult.getPicklistValues();
        for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : cipPLE)
        {
            cipOptions.add(new PicklistOption(f.getValue(),f.getLabel()));
        }             
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult stateFieldResult = Experiential_Enrollment_Detail__c.State_List__c.getDescribe();
        
        List<Experiential_Enrollment__c> currentOOSP = [SELECT Id, Name, Enrollment_State__c 
                                  FROM Experiential_Enrollment__c
                                  WHERE Id= :enrollmentIdVal];
        
        String enrollmentState = currentOOSP[0].Enrollment_State__c;
        
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> statePLE = stateFieldResult.getPicklistValues();
        System.debug('Enrollment State: '+enrollmentState);
        for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : statePLE)
        {
            try{
                if(f.getValue().contains(enrollmentState)==false){
                    stateOptions.add(new PicklistOption(f.getValue(),f.getLabel()));
                }
                
                //Manually check for Virginia due to it being contained in West Virginia
                if(enrollmentState=='Virginia' && f.getValue().contains('West Virginia')){
                    stateOptions.add(new PicklistOption(f.getValue(),f.getLabel()));
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.debug('An exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
            } 
        }

        return new OOSPOptions(cipOptions, stateOptions);
    }
```

**OOSP component**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="OutOfStatePlacementsController" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="oospRecord" type="Experiential_Enrollment__c" />
    <aura:attribute name="oospDetailRecords" type="Experiential_Enrollment_Detail__c[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="oospTotalCount" type="Integer" default="0" />
    <aura:attribute name="oospId" type="String" />
...


<aura:iteration items="{!v.oospDetailRecords}" var="detail" indexVar="idx">
                                <aura:if isTrue="{!!v.oospRecord.Is_Locked__c}">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <lightning:combobox data-index="{!idx}" name="{!'cipType' + idx}" value="{!detail.CIP_Type__c}" placeholder="Select CIP Type" options="{! v.cipOptions }" onchange="{!c.handleDetailChange}" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <lightning:combobox data-index="{!idx}" name="{!'stateList' + idx}" value="{!detail.State_List__c}" placeholder="Select State" options="{! v.stateOptions }" onchange="{!c.handleDetailChange}" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <lightning:input data-index="{!idx}" type="number" name="{!'enrollmentCount' + idx}" min="0" max="999999" value="{!detail.Enrollment_Count__c}" onchange="{!c.handleDetailChange}" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                                            <lightning:buttonIcon name="{!'remove' + idx}" iconName="utility:close" variant="bare" onclick="{!c.handleRemoveDetail}" alternativeText="Remove" />
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <aura:set attribute="else">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <lightning:formattedText value="{!detail.CIP_Type__c}" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <lightning:formattedText value="{!detail.State_List__c}" />                                        
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!detail.Enrollment_Count__c}" maximumFractionDigits="0"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </aura:set>
                            </aura:if>
                            </aura:iteration>
...

<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.oospId}" objectApiName="Experiential_Enrollment__c">
                        <br/>
                        <h3 class="slds-text-heading_small slds-hyphenate">Comments</h3>
                        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap SARA" >
                            <div class="slds-col_padded slds-size_3-of-3">
                                <lightning:outputField fieldName="Comments__c"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
```

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive. It's `oopsId`, not `oopsid`.

Comment: @sfdcfox good catch but that's not the issue.  It is still undefined with the matching case

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your `OOSPOptions` declaration, but check if it's `@AuraEnabled`.

You'd need to declare your return object's individual fields as `@AuraEnabled` for you to see them in your aura JS.

From the doc:

> When an instance of an Apex class is returned from a server-side action, the instance is serialized to JSON by the framework. Only the values of public instance properties and methods annotated with @AuraEnabled are serialized and returned.

An example:

```
@AuraEnabled public String Id { get; set; }
@AuraEnabled public String Name { get; set; }
```

Make sure to include the `{get; set;}` as well.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_returning_data.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_AuraEnabled.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_returning_data.htm

Comment: Here is the class.  My issue is that the oospId is not related to the OOSPOptions object though . 
 I am trying to reference the value from a different part of the code where it doesn't see it.  ```public class OOSPOptions {
        @AuraEnabled public List<PicklistOption> cipOptions {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public List<PicklistOption> stateOptions {get;set;}

        public OOSPOptions() {}

        public OOSPOptions(List<PicklistOption> cips, List<PicklistOption> states) {
            this.cipOptions = cips;
            this.stateOptions = states;
        }
    }```